# Intercept in linear model with 2 factors

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, lm

I have linear model

```
lmB <- lm(vsnIntensity ~  Donor + Condition  ,data = check)
```

Donor and Condition are both factors and vsnIntensity is continous 
The model in mathematical notation, (I think) is 
$$
y_{ij} = \alpha + \beta_i + \gamma_j + \epsilon_{ij}
$$

Where $\alpha$ is the intercept, which is the mean of the reference donor and condition.
$\beta_i$ are the coefficients (effects) for all conditions except the reference condition.
$\gamma_j$ are the coefficients (effects) for all the donors except the reference donor.
Is the mathematical notation correct?

When I fit the model I am getting:

```
  > lmB <- lm(vsnIntensity ~  Donor + Condition  ,data = check)
  > data.frame(coefficients(lmB))
                 coefficients.lmB.
  (Intercept)        18.15866653
  Donor185            0.06377651
  Donor234            0.30834387
  Donor235            0.36166529
  Donor236            0.09642398
  ConditionCMP       -0.01566147
  ConditionGMP        0.20452979
  ConditionMEP        0.06511231
```

However, computing the mean for the reference donor and condition using `aggregate` I have different values:

```
   Group.1 Group.2        x
   1      HSC     132 18.06667
   2      CMP     132 18.26274
   3      GMP     132 18.31288
   4      MEP     132 18.24636
   5      HSC     185 18.14692
   6      CMP     185 18.20435
```

Why Do I have a different value for the Intercept than the group mean for the reference factors and why when I am using only a single factor e.g.

```
lmB <- lm(vsnIntensity ~  Condition  ,data = check)
```

the intercept is the group mean for the reference condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `aggregate()` is giving you the *actual* means by condition. That is, it should equal what you get from doing something like: `with(check, tapply(donor, condition, mean))`.

However, the intercept is the *model-implied* or *predicted value* for when the subjects are in the reference conditions for both `donor` and `condition`.

The model-implied solution does not always equal the actual observed values, especially if `donor` and `condition` might be correlated.

I believe this is correct, but I would need to see the data and/or what you typed in for the `aggregate()` command to know for sure.